# List RDS instances with greater than 7 snapshot retention period

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-rds

Can someone please help me on listing RDS instances with more than 7 days of snapshot retention period. I am trying something as below, but not working:

`` aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[*].Attachments[?BackupRetentionPeriod > `7`].DBInstanceIdentifier' ``

Comment: "but not working" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: I don't see `Attachments` in the output from [describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html). Try: `DBInstances[?BackupRetentionPeriod > 7]`

Comment: Thanks @jarmod . This worked:
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[?BackupRetentionPeriod > `7`].DBInstanceIdentifier'

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Attachments` property in the output from [describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html).

Instead, try using:

```
DBInstances[?BackupRetentionPeriod > 7].DBInstanceIdentifier
```